# tracking conversion (visit from A to B) in a custom report

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like to track in custom report specifically how many users came from my main page / to subpage: /somesubpage

So basically I'd like to see a graph of daily visitors that went from:
/ -> /somesubpage

How is it possible to visualize that in custom report?

I tried selecting visitor as a metric, page as a dimension, but I'm not sure if I should filter or set the landing page somehow?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create new custom report
2. Choose type as "Flat table"
3. Choose first dimension as "Page" and last dimension as "Next Page Path"
4. Add metric "Visits"
5. As filter choose "include"-"Next Page Path" - "RegEx" - "/somesubpage"

You can use&customize my template, I created it and shared for you:
https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=E-68JHgNQq2rmJBg3W_pUA

Comment: When I add regex for the next page path as (\/subpage|\/subpage\/) it will display the same page url in both page and next page path columns. Do you have any idea why is that?

Comment: I think, you can try to add "exclude" filter for "page" matching Regexp (\/subpage|\/subpage\/)

So you will have 2 filters:
1. "Include" for "Next page"
2. "Exclude" for "Page"

Not sure, that it will be work, but you can try to do it.